# Get timestamp in the log file by using .conf file logstash

Tags: logstash, elk

I have a .conf file that I want to get the timestamp from the log file not the system date. There for what are the changes that I should do in the .conf file the feed through logstash to Elasticsearch? logs are feeding fine to ELK stack only issue is it get the system time not the time from log file.

My log lines are as follows

> `11812211602170772|2019-12-19 00:00:00 004|SPP_005206|hsenid217@gmail.com|APP_016179|prov|live|IdeaMart||caas|http|94771133726||||subs-rec-charg-notify|sms|unknown|subscriber|16.02|LKR|[{"currencyCode":"LKR", "buyingRate": 1, "sellingRate": 1}]|subscription|94771133726||freeRegistration|P9545|success|success|457d|77850|dialog||percentageFromMonthlyRevenue|70||||S1000|SUCCESS|118122116020074|prorate|0|||||||||||monthly||||Mobile Account||dialog||REG_PENDING|REGISTERED`

My .conf file is as follows

```
input{  file{
        path => "/home/rehan/Projects/SIEM/Splunk/test3/sdp-server/*"
        type => "translog"
        start_position => "beginning"   } }

filter {     grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{NUMBER:field1}\|%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:field2} %{NUMBER:field3}\|%{WORD:field4}\|*\|%{WORD:field5}\@%{WORD:field6}\.com\|%{WORD:field7}\|%{WORD:field8}\|%{WORD:field9}\|%{WORD:field10}\|\|%{WORD:field11}\|%{WORD:field12}\|%{NUMBER:field13}\|\|\|\|%{WORD:field14}\-%{WORD:field15}\-%{WORD:field16}\-%{WORD:field17}\|%{WORD:field18}\|%{WORD:field19}\|%{WORD:field20}\|%{NUMBER:field21}\|%{WORD:field22}\|\[\{\"%{WORD:field23}\"\:\"%{WORD:field24}\"\,\ \"%{WORD:field25}\"\:\ %{NUMBER:field26}\, \"%{WORD:field27}\"\: %{NUMBER:field28}\}]\|%{WORD:field29}\|%{NUMBER:field30}\|\|%{WORD:field31}\|%{WORD:field32}\|%{WORD:field33}\|%{WORD:field34}\|%{WORD:field35}\|%{NUMBER:field36}\|%{WORD:field37}\|\|%{WORD:field38}\|%{NUMBER:field39}\|\|\|\|%{WORD:field40}\|%{WORD:field41}\|%{NUMBER:field42}\|%{WORD:field43}\|%{NUMBER:field43}\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|%{WORD:field44}" }     }

    date{       match => [ "field2" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss SSS" ]       } }

output{     elasticsearch{
        hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
        index => "translog"     } }
```

Any anyone give a example suggestions that how I should change the .conf file ?

Comment: right now your `field2` will have this value `2019-12-19 00:00:00`. What do you want to have in `field2`? include `format` too

Comment: I want to get field2 value as timestamp and show it in dashboard not the system/pc time that log entered. There for i'm asking what are be the changes  that i should do in .conf file to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below answer**:

```
input{
        file{
            path => "/home/rehan/Projects/SIEM/Splunk/test3/sdp-server/*"
            type => "translog"
            start_position => "beginning"
        }
    }

    filter {
         grok {
                match => { "message" => "%{NUMBER:field1}\|%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:field2} %{NUMBER:field3}\|%{WORD:field4}\|*\|%{WORD:field5}\@%{WORD:field6}\.com\|%{WORD:field7}\|%{WORD:field8}\|%{WORD:field9}\|%{WORD:field10}\|\|%{WORD:field11}\|%{WORD:field12}\|%{NUMBER:field13}\|\|\|\|%{WORD:field14}\-%{WORD:field15}\-%{WORD:field16}\-%{WORD:field17}\|%{WORD:field18}\|%{WORD:field19}\|%{WORD:field20}\|%{NUMBER:field21}\|%{WORD:field22}\|\[\{\"%{WORD:field23}\"\:\"%{WORD:field24}\"\,\ \"%{WORD:field25}\"\:\
     %{NUMBER:field26}\, \"%{WORD:field27}\"\: %{NUMBER:field28}\}]\|%{WORD:field29}\|%{NUMBER:field30}\|\|%{WORD:field31}\|%{WORD:field32}\|%{WORD:field33}\|%{WORD:field34}\|%{WORD:field35}\|%{NUMBER:field36}\|%{WORD:field37}\|\|%{WORD:field38}\|%{NUMBER:field39}\|\|\|\|%{WORD:field40}\|%{WORD:field41}\|%{NUMBER:field42}\|%{WORD:field43}\|%{NUMBER:field43}\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|\|%{WORD:field44}" }
        }
        date {
            match => [ "field2", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
            target => "@timestamp"
        }
    }

    output{ 
        elasticsearch{
            hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
            index => "translog"
        }
    }
```